# Next.js client debug with VSCode shows transpiled JS

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, next.js, transpiler

I have a little Next.js app (all dependencies are the up-to-date.)

VS Code shows transpiled code when debugging my async function:

[image: On debug, VS Code shows transpiled TSX]

Chrome's `devTools` seems working as expected (but showing the filename with some hash added to its end):

[image: Opening files for debug in DevTools]

I'm using [debug configuration recommended by Next.JS](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging#debugging-with-vs-code). My `launch.json`:

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "command": "yarn dev",
      "name": "Server-side",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "node-terminal"
    },
    {
      "name": "Client-side",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    {
      "command": "yarn dev",
      "name": "Full stack",
      "request": "launch",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "debugWithChrome",
        "pattern": "started server on .+, url: (https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s"
      },
      "type": "node-terminal"
    },
  ],
  "version": "0.2.0"
}
```

Any ideas why this is happenning (and how to fix it)?